# How to add a 3D model in Unity (obj+mtl)

Tags: unity-game-engine

i created a scene with some moving spheres.
Now i would like to replace the spheres with 3D models of a satellite which i found online.
Inside the folder i found the following files: *sat.jpg*, *sat.obj*, *sat.mtl*.
I extracted the files in a folder and put it inside my project.
I tried to load the .obj file in my scene succesfully, but the object is gray and has no colors/texture.

How can i insert the object correctly to show the texture?

PS. I opened the model in Blender and i can see the satellite with the texture. Unfortunately i've never used Blender and i don't know if it can hep me somehow.

Comment: You need to add a `Material` to the 3D model, then assign the texture (`sat.jpg`) to the `Material`'s Albedo property. You can read up on Materials [in the Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Materials.html).

Comment: Thank you Velorexe, it worked and now i can see the texture.

Comment: Glad you got it to work!